# How to reverse label and button positions of input[type=upload] in IE without altering html

Tags: html, css

I wish to style an upload button. I do my job fine with ::-webkit-upload-button but IE unlike chrome displays the button on the right and the label on the left(?).

**I cannot alter the html** by adding buttons/labels/divs because it comes from a form generated from somewhere I cannot tamper with.

I used ::-ms-value in css but it does not seem to work. The below css gets completely ignored. I tried some things I found but nothing helped much. Any suggestions?

```
#uniqueID input[type=file]::-ms-value {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: -9999px !important;
    text-align: right !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I did it with css only using margins and text-indent:

```
#uniqueID input[type=file]::-ms-value {
    margin-right: -699px;
}

#uniqueID input[type=file]::-ms-browse{
    margin-right: 1020px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#uniqueID input[type=file] {
     text-indent: 99px;
}
```